# How is the time intereval calculated for symmetric key re-negoatition in UK Security Standard – Use of Cryptography?

Tags: aes, keys, aes-gcm

According to point 10.6.4 (Encryption in Transit) in [Security Standard –Use of Cryptography](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/882760/dwp-ss007-security-standard-use-of-cryptography-v1.1.pdf), one of the criteria for key renegotiation is timeout ,

> Encrypted sessions MUST re-negotiate new symmetric keys after one of
> the following criteria is met:
>
> - The “counter” in CTR or GCM mode has exhausted all possible unique values for the initialisation vector. The standard deployment using
>   AES permits 64GB of information to be passed and no more;
> - **8 hours have passed**, which is a best-practice requirement to prevent initialisation vector re-use where the exact amount of data
>   transmitted cannot be trackedand/or different modes are used.

**Question 1.** How is the value of 8 hours obtained ?what are the inputs to the calculation?

Comment: Initially, I didn't get what the question was: the session key is to be renegotiated after some amount of data or some amount of time since the previous negotiation, whichever comes first / is the criteria. It is unspecified how that time is measured (number of beats of a local quartz crystal divided by its rated frequency comes to mind), the exact start time (start of the first message in the negotiation comes to mind), or how the exact amount of data ( G = $10^9$ or $2^{30}$, exactly what's counted..) but this is left at the discretion of the implementation, I guess. Update: clearer now!

Comment: I modified the question trying to make it more clearer.

Comment: Ah, I think you are asking, "why is 8 hours the required interval for negotiation? How was that value arrived at?"

Comment: When we consider that with AES-NI one can reach around [3GB per second](https://calomel.org/aesni_ssl_performance.html) 22 seconds is enough tho pass the limit. I still consider the context is missing and maybe only the authors can provide the reason if any exist.

Comment: Could you ask the authors and inform us?

Comment: I can not find an email for the authors . also ,a statement made  on DWP website : "Please note, the Department for Work and Pensions (DWP) is unable to reply to general enquiries or questions about these security standards and policies."

Comment: link to the website: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/dwp-procurement-security-policies-and-standards

Comment: Interesting, what happened to right to learn! So they wrote a standard and none can ask about how they derived. Then, I don't call it a standard, it is a bunch of letters.